# Error: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned long'

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting the below warning message when passing a pointer to long integer as a function argument.

> warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned
>   long' to parameter of type 'unsigned long *'; remove *
>   [-Wint-conversion] reverse(*n1);
>
> Recursion_Reverse.c:16:29: note: passing argument to parameter 'n1'
>   here: `void reverse(unsigned long *n1)`

Here is the code snippet. Thanks in Advance!

```
void reverse(unsigned long *);

int main() { 
    unsigned long n; 

    printf("\nEnter Any Nnmber:");    
    scanf("%lu",&n); 

    reverse(&n);    
    printf("\nAfter Reverse,n=%lu\n",n); 

    return 0;
}


void reverse(unsigned long *n1) {
    unsigned long sum=0;
    if(*n1>0) 
    {
        sum=(sum*10)+(*n1%10);
        *n1/=10;
        reverse(*n1);
    }

    *n1=sum;
}
```

Comment: Format code as well as question first.

Comment: Your error message is telling you exactly what to do. Remove the `*` from `reverse(*n1);` inside the `reverse` function.

Answer (score 1):

From inside your `void reverse(unsigned long *n1)` function you are calling it recursively with:

```
reverse(*n1);
```

So you are passing a direct `unsigned long` instead of its pointer.
As you are expecting its pointer just change it to:

```
reverse(n1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong part:

```
void reverse(unsigned long *n1) {
  ....
  reverse(*n1);
}
```

reverse needs a pointer, you provide a value (dereferenced pointer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to function each continue(E.g. pass to function) to the `sum`.

```
unsigned long reverse_aux(unsigned long n, unsigned long sum){
    return n > 0 ? reverse_aux(n / 10, sum * 10 + n % 10) : sum;
}

void reverse(unsigned long *n1) {
    *n1 = reverse_aux(*n1, 0);
}
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.